# Central Limit Theorem, what does it really say?

Tags: central-limit-theorem

I know that the Central Limit Theorem states that if a random sample of size $n$ is drawn from iid random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$, then the variable
$$
Z = \frac{\hat x - E(X) }{{\rm sd}(\hat x)}\text{ is }\mathcal N(0,1) 
$$
as $n$ is big enough (where $\hat x$ denotes the sample average).

My question is: What about $\hat x$, does it also converge to a normal distribution?

Comment: For intuition about the CLT, please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3734.  The short answer (given by [laws of large numbers](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/22804/what-theories-should-every-statistician-know)) is no: $\hat x$ converges to the common expectation of the $X_i$.

Comment: Do you mean what does the *value* $\hat x$ converge to, or what does the *distribution* of $\hat x$ converge to?

Answer (score 4):

The central limit theorem says the variable $Z$ converges in distribution to the standard normal.

$$Z=\frac{\hat{x}-E(X)}{\text{sd}(\hat{x})} \overset{D}{\rightarrow} N(0,1)$$

Rearrange this at a fixed value of $n$ (number of samples) to get, approximately:

$$\hat{x} \sim N(E(X),\text{Var}(\hat{x})) $$

where $\text{Var}(\hat{x})=\frac{\text{Var}(X)}{n}$ is the variance of the sample mean. You might interpret this as the distribution of $\hat{x}$ tends towards being normal with mean $E(X)$ and variance $\frac{\text{Var}(X)}{n}$.

For large values of $n$, the variance will tend to $0$. which means that the normal distribution of $\hat{x}$ will actually converge to a point mass distribution at $E(X)$. Convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability to that constant. So

$$\hat{x} \overset{P}{\rightarrow} E(X)$$

Of course this is just the weak law of large numbers. (The strong law stating that the convergence in almost sure.)

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks for pointing that out. I changed that line to be approximate.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this answer of mine](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/22532/6633) which says pretty much the same things.